# (C#) why does Visual Studio say it's an object while GetType says it's a Func<object>?

Tags: c#, function, gettype

C# newbie question here.  The following code (taken from the book "C# From Novice to Professional" by Christian Gross, Apress) gives an error:

```
worksheet.Add("C3", CellFactories.DoAdd(worksheet["A2"], worksheet["B1"]));
```

The reason is that the method `DoAdd()` does not accept the given arguments.

```
public static Func<object> DoAdd(Func<object> cell1, Func<object> cell2) {...}
```

VS claims that both args in the method call above are of type `object` whereas the method accepts only `Func<object>`. But the *value* of both worksheet elements is of type `Func<object>`:

```
worksheet.Add("A2", CellFactories.Static(10.0));
```

where this `Static` method just returns the given value:

```
public static Func<object> Static(object value) { return () => value; }
// return type= Func<object>
```

When I cast `worksheet["A2"]` as `Func<object>`, the code does work.

But there is something I don't understand.  The type of the object instance is `Func<object>`.  I have used the `GetType()` method to see proof of this, and compare the object types of the original elements to that of the cast object (which IS accepted):

```
Console.Writeline(worksheet["A2"].GetType());

// now cast to the correct type (why can't it do that implicitly, btw?)
Funk1 = worksheet["A2"] as Func<object>;

Console.Writeline(Funk1.GetType());
```

.. and they are ALL identical!  (Type =  `System.Func'1[System.Object]`)

And even when I use the `.Equals()` method to compare both types, it returns `true`.

Yet, VS sees the first object instance as type `object` in the method call. Why? Why does the called method 'see' the argument as a different type than the GetType() returns?
(and if so, what good is the `GetType()` method?)

Thanks a lot for your advice/comments! (It's kinda hard to learn the language if the book examples give an error and you don't see the reason - hence, got the vague impression that something is wrong either with `GetType()` or VS.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand the difference between *dynamic typing* and *static typing*.  The indexer for your `worksheet` object most likely has a static type of `object`.

```
public object this[string cell]{get{...}set{...}}
```

Because all objects in C# [inherit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(computer_science)) from type `object`, the object reference stored in a cell can be a reference to *any* object.

That is, because a delegate (such as `Func<T>`) **is** an `object`, it can be stored in an `object` reference:

```
Func<object> func = ()=>return "foo";
object o = func; // this compiles fine
```

And the compiler can figure this all out, because it understands implicitly that a derived class can be stored in a reference to a base class.

What the compiler cannot do automatically, is determine what the dynamic type, or *run time type* of an object is.

```
Func<object> func = ()=>return "foo";
object o = func; // this compiles fine
func = o; // <-- ERROR
```

The compiler doesn't know that the `object` stored in `o` is actually of type `Func<object>`.  It's not supposed to keep track of this.  This is information that must be checked at run time.

```
func = (Func<object>)o; // ok!
```

The above line of code compiles into something that behaves similarly to this:

```
if(o == null)
    func = null;
else if(typeof(Func<object>).IsAssignableFrom(func.GetType()))
    __copy_reference_address__(func, o); // made up function!  demonstration only
else throw new InvalidCastException();
```

In this way, any cast (conversion from one type to another) can be checked at run time to make sure it's valid and safe.

Comment: +1 Absolutely right, however perhaps a bit too complicated of an explanation for someone new to C# and/or programming.

Answer (score 2):

Others have given accurate and detailed answers, but here I will try to explain in simple language.

When you write `worksheet["A2"]` you really are calling a member function of `worksheet`

`worksheet` has a member function named `[]` that accepts a `string` and returns an `object`

The signature of the member function `[]` looks like `object this[string id]`

So the function `worksheet["A2"]` returns something that is an `object`. It could be an `int` or a `string` or many other things. All the compiler knows is that it will be an `object`.

In the example, you have it returning a `Func<object>`. This is fine, because `Func<object>` *is* an `object`. However, you then pass the result of that function in as a parameter to another function.

The problem here is that the compiler only knows that `worksheet["A2"]` returns an `object`. That is as specific as the compiler can be.
So the compiler sees that `worksheet["A2"]` is an object, and you are trying to pass the object to a function that does not accept `object` as a parameter.

So here you have to tell the compiler "hey dummy, that's a `Func<object>`" by casting the returned object to the correct type.

```
worksheet.Add("C3", CellFactories.DoAdd(worksheet["A2"], worksheet["B1"]));
```

can be re-written as

```
worksheet.Add("C3", CellFactories.DoAdd((Func<object>)worksheet["A2"], (Func<object>)worksheet["B1"]));
```

Now the compiler knows that, even though the `[]` function returns an `object`, it can treat it like a `Func<object>`.

side note: You're probably doing too much on one line. That may be hard for people to read in the future.

> Why does the called method 'see' the argument as a different type than the GetType() returns?

The compiler only knows that `worksheet[]` returns an object. The compiler can not call `GetType()` on it at compile time.

> What good is the GetType() method?

There are quite a few uses and abuses of the `GetType()` method, but that is an entirely different discussion. ;)

In summary, the compiler does not assume anything about types. This is a *good thing* because you get a compile time error when you try to fit this square peg into a round hole. If the compiler did not complain, this error would surface at run-time, which means you would probably need a unit test to detect the problem.

You can get around this problem by telling the compiler "I know for a fact that this thing **is** a round peg, trust me." and then it will compile.
If you lie to the compiler, you will get a run-time error when that code is executed.

This is called "static typing". The opposing philosophy is called "dynamic typing" where type checks are done at run-time. Static vs dynamic is a lengthy debate and you should probably research it on your own if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

> VS claims that both args in the method call above are of type object whereas the method accepts only Func. But the value of both worksheet elements is of type Func

Yes, but the declared type is `object`. The compiler can't know that the actual runtime type will be `Func<object>`, so an explicit cast is necessary.